# How to compare data from two different databases?

Tags: java, database

I am trying to find a solution for my problem. The problem statement

1. I have two different DB's Oracle and AS400. Both the databases has the same structure and same tables (but different table names obviously).
2. AS400 gets updated via the internet and Oracle gets updated via the store or from the warehouse.
3. Both the DB's are synched on daily basis, after the synch we need a report to be generated on daily basis to know if there is any difference in the data.
4. The compare need to be done from both the sides first get the data from AS400 and compare with Oracle DB and vice versa.
5. We are talking about 10 million records here. First time it would be the whole DB compare and the subsequent report would be only on the records that got changed or newly added to DB (this is fairly simple and easy to take care), but the first time compare is what we trying to achieve.

I know ETL process would really make the job easy but we don't have ETL tool so trying to find a solution using Java. Any suggestion that can help us is really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 1) use Joda library in Java and date arithmetic will be a breeze for you in Java. 2) Use batches to fetch records , and the hits will be minimal on DB.

Comment: @BBBZone **Both the DB's are synched on daily basis, after the synch we need a report to be generated on daily basis to know if there is any difference in the data.** -- Small clarification need for this statement. After sync both db's will have the same data right. AS400 data will be update in oracle and oracle data will be updated in AS400. Then what is the need for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but Liquibase supports both DB2 and Oracle.

[The page that talks about their *diff* function](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach is to setup two datasources, grab the data from each store and compare it.

Of course your memory will blow up with 10 million record, so maybe try grabbing and comparing the data in batches (beware of updates happening while doing this)

Further performance enhancement might be gained if you use multiple thread

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the memory consumption for the initial compare, why don't look into using some form of hashing of the record data. Assuming a decent primary key (a long for instance) and SHA-1 digest, that would mean 4+20 = 24 bytes per record, or roughly 200 Mb per database.

Answer (score 0):

> Both the DB's are synched on daily basis, after the synch we need a report to be generated on daily basis to know if there is any difference in the data.

Depending on how the synchronization is done, you might be able to grab just the daily transactions input to the Oracle database and the AS400 database.  It would be much faster to process these daily transaction files than to process both of the entire databases.

If there are no daily transaction files, than that's your first step.  Create daily transaction files.